# SQL- group by two columns, take average and count sample for each case

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, multiple-columns, average

My table looks like below

```
x   y    z
a   ab   2
a   ab   4
a   ac   4
b   ab   6
b   ab   4
b   ad   8
c   ac   10
c   ac   10
```

What I am looking for is this:

```
x   y    avg_z  number_of_sample
a   ab   3      2
a   ac   4      1
b   ab   5      2
b   ad   8      1
c   ac   10     2
```

Basically I have right now this:

```
SELECT x, y, AVG(z) AS avg_z
FROM table1
GROUP BY x, y
```

But I can't create a next column with number of sample for each case. Do you have idea how I could solve this?

Regards

Comment: Hi. What DB are you using? PostgreSQL, My-SQL, etc..

Comment: have you tried something like `COUNT(id) as number_of_samples`? (id is unique for each column so `COUNT(id)` should be the group size ... though I haven't used SQL in a while)

Comment: @Albina PostgresSQL

Comment: see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oBf198VKNAxbFrASTnJgp7/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT x, y, AVG(z) AS avg_z, COUNT(*) AS number_of_sample
FROM table1
GROUP BY x, y
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

```
SELECT x, y, AVG(z) AS avg_z, COUNT(*) AS number_of_sample
FROM table1
GROUP BY x, y
```

**Long Answer** (How query is executed by the database)

Assume we have a table named **data** with the following data:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 2 |

**Step 1: Data Retrieval**

The database engine retrieves the data from the data table.

**Step 2: Grouping**

The data is grouped based on unique combinations of values in columns x and y. The groups are as follows:

Group 1: (x='A', y=1)

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |

Group 2: (x='B', y=2)

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2 |

and so one for the rest of the values

**Step 3: Aggregation**

For each group, the COUNT(*) function is applied to calculate the number of occurrences within each group:

Group 1: (x='A', y=1), COUNT(*) = 2

Group 2: (x='B', y=2), COUNT(*) = 1

and so on

**Step 4: Result Generation**

The final result set is generated, combining the grouped columns (x and y) with the calculated occurrence_count for each group:

| x | y | occurrence_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 1 |

**Step 5: Query Completion**

The result set is presented to the user or application that requested the data.